# How to set the laravel conf to use mailgun

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I am using Laravel 8 + queues + Mailgun API to send emails from my local machine.

I can't send emails. I have this error :

```
[2020-12-19 11:50:26] local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number at C:\\Users\\Dominique\\Documents\\Workspace\\market-gardener\\market-gardener-back\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php:269)
[stacktrace]
```

I think I have a configuration issues somewhere. I tried a lot of things without success. My conf :

.env :

```
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox___xxxxx_____________.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=secret___xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx______
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

config/email :

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],
```

Is this kind of conf correct? Where are my errors? Of course I already tried to clear the cache and config.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version of the Mailgun setup I use:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.eu.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=address@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=example
MAIL_USERNAME=address@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="123abc456def"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The keys are coupled to the default `config/mail.php` file as seen here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/mail.php

Note the usage of `tls` and port number `587`. The `MAIL_HOST` may also differ. Mailgun should probably have a page on their website where this configuration is outlined.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter was missing in the.env ([see the doc here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#configuration))

I only added **MAIL_MAILER=mailgun** in the .env , and it works fine now.

My .env is now :

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox___xxxxx_____________.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=secret___xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx______
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you provide all the values of the environment variable
if not it won't work. in my own case, I added this line in my env file

```
MAILGUN_SECRET=6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd
```